# Run Excel Macro from Outlook and Return a Value to Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have the following code I am running from Outlook to run a macro in Excel.  I know I can trap an error if the macro itself fails to run, but I'd like to know what the result was when the macro successfully executes.  In my mock example Excel function, I would like to return the value "Yes" to Outlook.

**Outlook part**

```
Dim excelWorkbook As Excel.workbook
Set excelWorkbook = GetObject(workbookPath & workbookName) ' variables contain full path and file name

' This works
excelWorkbook.Application.Run "functions.didItWork"

Dim testVal As Variant

' This gives me an error "Compile error: Expected: end of statement"
testVal = excelWorkbook.Application.Run "functions.didItWork"
```

**Excel part - obviously not my final code :)**

```
Function didItWork()

didItWork = "Yes"

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there: you need to use parentheses when calling a function and using the return value

```
testVal = excelWorkbook.Application.Run("functions.didItWork")
MsgBox testVal
```